# Array error when XORing by key stream

Tags: python, xor

I'm trying to XOR a file (encoded_data.bin)with a key stream (key.bin) and keep getting an error "array index out of range". The key file is longer than the data file. Any help is appreciated. I'm fairly new to python btw - if its not obvious already.

```
import array
k=open("key.bin", "rb")
s=open("encoded_data.bin", "rb")
t=k.read()
r=s.read()
a1 = array.array('B', (t))
a2 = array.array('B', (r))
for i in range(len(a1)):
   a1[i] ^= a2[i]

   print a1.tostring()

   k.close
   s.close
```

Comment: The statement `k.close` does nothing.  You probably want `k.close()` and `s.close()` -- and you probably want to move those statements out of the for loop.

Comment: Well, first of all, try better variable names. Your loop goes to the length of a1 (the length of the key.bin data) which, as you stated, is longer than the encoded_data.bin file. So obviously, a2 is going to have fewer elements than a1. You could "fix" it by changing range(len(a1)) to range(len(a2)), but that will not work after you change the contents of encoded_data.bin. What you probably want to do is a bit more complicated than I can put in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the key file is longer, as you have said, and you are looping for each byte in the key file:

```
for i in range(len(a1)):
    a1[i] ^= a2[i]
```

Once `i` is equal to `len(a2)` you are going to get this exception when you try to fetch `a2[i]`, as `i` is out of the bounds of the array.

It's not clear exactly what the correct solution is based on your question, but if you know that the data will always be smaller than the key, just use the length of the data instead:

```
for i in range(len(a2)):
```

If your goal is to have the key repeat when the data is larger than the key, the solution will be a bit more involved.

Comment: He's probably [trying to implement the one-time pad encryption algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad). The key should never repeat, so using key length is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use the built-in `zip` function. It allows you to loop over two iterables at once, which is appropriate for your case.

```
plaintext = []
for key_byte, ciphertext_byte in zip(a1, a2):
    plaintext.append(chr(ord(key_byte) ^ ord(ciphertext_byte)))

print ''.join(plaintext)
```

If there are extra bytes in the ciphertext, they will be dismissed. If there are extra bytes in the key, they won't be used.

---

I take it that you're implementing the one time pad. Let me suggest that you use [`bytearray`s](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray) here:

```
key = byterray(k.read())
ciphertext = bytearray(s.read())
plaintext = bytearray()

for key_byte, ciphertext_byte in zip(key, ciphertext):
    plaintext.append(key_byte ^ ciphertext_byte)

print plaintext
```

Comment: Or in this case, you could pack the whole thing into a list comprehension or generator expression.:  `[key_byte ^ encrypte_byte for key_byte,encrypt_byte in zip(a1,a2)]` -- or even `[operator.xor(*item) for item in zip(a1,a2)]`

Comment: @mgilson That's true! There were a few `chr`'s and `ord`'s that I had left aside though, so I think it's a bit clearer using a loop

Answer (score 0):

A solution like this will work in your case and in the event your data is longer than your key (which, of course, is a major cryptographic no-no!):

```
def xorloop(l, xors):
    return [l[i] ^ xors[i % len(xors)] for i in xrange(len(l))]
```

It takes iterables of XOR-able values, like so:

```
>>> xorloop([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8])
[7, 5, 11, 2, 2]
```

You can adapt this to strings fairly easily using `array` as you have in your example.

Comment: You probably meant "in the event your data is longer than your key" : )

Comment: @ThomasOrozco That'll teach me to post before I finish my coffee. Thanks :-)

Comment: Haha, have a nice coffee then! : )